# Meaning of marginal prior distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I have a variable $\mu$ with distribution, given $\phi$ of $ \mu|\phi \sim N(\phi, \sigma^2)$, and the distribution of $\phi$ is $\phi \sim N(\nu, \tau^2)$. (Here, $\sigma^2,\nu$ and $\tau^2$ are known).

I need to find the marginal prior distribution of $\mu$, but am not sure what this means.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've used $\theta$ without relating it to anything. I suspect you mean to use $\phi$ there. As for what "the marginal prior distribution of $\mu$" means, it means to find the prior distribution of $\mu$ not conditioned on $\phi$. this involves integrating $\phi$ out so that your prior for $\mu$ is purely in terms of $\sigma^2$, $\nu$ and $\tau^2$. It's not terribly difficult. As a routine textbook style question, this sounds like it falls under the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag. Please check the link and if it applies, make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I do mean $\phi$. I'll make those changes.